# How to find team_id on Bountysource?

Tags: bountysource

I would like to use [Bountysource Badges](http://blog.bountysource.com/post/87257081709/bountysource-badges) which display all bounties for the specific team, e.g.:

[image]

However the URL for the badge is:

```
https://api.bountysource.com/badge/team?team_id=69
```

and the destination URL is: https://www.bountysource.com/teams/facebook/bounties

How do I know `facebook` = `69`?

How do I find the `team_id` I should use for bounties of [any team](https://www.bountysource.com/teams)?

Or what other badge I can use to list all the open bounties that the team has open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the [secret API](http://github.com/badges/shields/issues/289):

```
curl https://api.bountysource.com/teams/facebook \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.bountysource+json; version=2'
```